# Laravel OrderBy Nested Collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using a Roles package (similar to entrust). I'm trying to sort my User::all() query on roles.id or roles.name

The following is all working

```
User::with('roles');
```

This returns a Collection, with a Roles relation that also is a collection.. Like this:

[image]

> I'm trying to get all users, but ordered by their role ID.

I tried the following without success
**maybe because 'roles' returns a collection? And not the first role?**

```
return App\User::with(['roles' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('roles.id', 'asc');
}])->get();
```

And this

```
return App\User::with('roles')->orderBy('roles.id','DESC')->get();
```

None of them are working. I'm stuck! Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the help of [`joins`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#joins) like this:

```
App\User::join('roles', 'users.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
        ->orderBy('roles.id', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What if user have multiple roles?

Comment: @RajenderJoshi - Didn't get you!

Comment: A user will only have 1 role. shame you can't enforce thaty using entrust. thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the dirty trick using collections. There might be a better way to achieve this(using Paginator class, I guess). This solution is definitely a disaster for huge tables.

```
$roles = Role::with('users')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
$sortedByRoleId = collect();

$roles->each(function ($role) use($sorted) {
    $sortedByRoleId->push($role->users);
});
$sortedByRoleId = $sortedByRoleId->flatten()->keyBy('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) which contains role id or name that you want to sort by.

Assume that the accessor name is roleCode. Then `App\User::all()->sortBy('roleCode')` will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your relations by using the query builder:

**notice the difference with your own example: I don't set `roles.id` but just `id`**

```
$users = App\User::with(['roles' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}])->get();
```

See the [Official Laravel Docs on Constraining Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Answer (score 0):

f you want to order the result based on nested relation column, you must use a chain of joins:

```
$values = User::query()->leftJoin('model_has_roles', function ($join) 
{
$join>on('model_has_roles.model_id', '=', 'users.id')
->where('model_has_roles.model_type', '=', 'app\Models\User');})
->leftJoin('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'model_has_roles.role_id')
->orderBy('roles.id')->get();
```

please note that if you want to order by multiple columns you could add 'orderBy' clause as much as you want:

```
->orderBy('roles.name', 'DESC')->orderby('teams.roles', 'ASC') //... ext
```

check my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61194625/10573560