# Laravel eloquent sort by role name on relationship model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm stuck with a problem where I have to sort / order a collection of models by their relationship's data.

I've got it setup like this:

Models:
`User`, `Team`, `TeamUser`, `Role`

The `TeamUser` model is a pivot model / table (containing `user_id` and `team_id`.
If it's worth mentioning I am also using [spatie/laravel-permissions](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/introduction/) for the roles.

How would I go forth when I  want to sort the users in a team by their `role.name`?
I'm talking about the `users()` relation in the `Team` model (see further down for code sample).
Some users have the role `team-leader` and most have the role `team-seller`. I've tried doing a ordinary `..->sortBy('role.name')` but that doesn't seem to work. Thanks in advance if anyone could help me out.

`User.php`

```
/**
 * Team relation
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team', 'team_users', 'user_id', 'team_id');
}
```

`Team.php`

```
/**
 * User relation
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'team_users', 'team_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to order the result based on nested relation column, you must use a chain of joins:

```
$values = Team::query()
      ->leftJoin('users', 'users.team_id', '=', 'teams.id')
      ->leftJoin('model_has_roles', function ($join) {
          $join->on('model_has_roles.model_id', '=', 'users.id')
               ->where('model_has_roles.model_type', '=', 'app\Models\User');
      })
      ->leftJoin('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'model_has_roles.role_id')
      ->orderBy('roles.name')
      ->get();
```

i have tried it, it work just fine.

please note that if you want to order by multiple columns you could add 'orderBy' clause as much as you want:

```
->orderBy('roles.name', 'DESC')->orderby('teams.name', 'ASC') //... ext
```

Comment: I tried using this method but it doesn't change anything at all about the order..
The one user i have currently with the role `team-seller` is always at the bottom. I tried both asc and desc order. 

`return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'team_users', 'team_id', 'user_id')->with(['roles' => function($q) {
            $q->orderByDesc('roles.name');
        }])->withTimestamps();`

Comment: i have updated my answer .. please let me know if it helps

Comment: That worked, did some few changes but I got the gist of how it works. Thank you for taking the time to help me out! :D

Comment: sadly the roles ordering didnt work with me, keep getting `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles' in 'order clause' `

Comment: are you using spatie permission package @ctf0 ?

Comment: yes, https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/introduction/

Comment: i suggest to make a question on so and share your code